# i am facing issue undefine window.tapstream object in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

in phonegap app i am working with tapstream api when i call  tapstream object  in angularjs controller it says object undefine how can i fix that  undefine object 
in application  it says undefine window.tapstream object

```
userappControllers.controller('LoginController', ['$scope', '$http', '$location','$rootScope','$cookies', 'translationService',
    function($scope, $http, $location, $rootScope, $cookies,  translationService) {
        window.tapstream.fireEvent('test-event', false);
}]);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
window.tapSteam = function () {
    alert("this is working");
}

myApp.controller('testController', function($scope) {
    window.tapSteam()
});
```

i tried this it's working
make sure to use **angular.module()** object.

**Note:**
As i have use myApp here as angular.module() object reference.